# Обработка событий от Media button

Tags: android

Всем привет, подскажите где возможна проблема?

Создаю mediaBrowserServiceCompat, который с помощью callback-ов  mediasession обрабатывает события от media button, почему то данный сервис ловит эти события только при первой установки приложения на устройства при последующих раннах из студии эвенты уже не ловятся.

Есть идеи с чем может быть связано?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
        <!--Максимальный приоритет-->
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".services.headset.HeadsetMediaBrowserService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

public class HeadsetMediaBrowserService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

```
private MediaSessionCompat _mediaSession;

private MediaSessionCompat.Callback _mediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCommand(String command, Bundle extras, ResultReceiver cb) {
        super.onCommand(command, extras, cb);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
        Log.d("_TEST_","HAVE EVENT");
        return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepare() {
        super.onPrepare();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        super.onPlay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomAction(String action, Bundle extras) {
        super.onCustomAction(action, extras);
    }
};

private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    _mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "HeadsetMediaBrowserService");

    _mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
    | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    _mediaSession.setCallback(_mediaSessionCallback);
    setSessionToken(_mediaSession.getSessionToken());
    _mediaSession.setActive(true);
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d("_TEST_", "MediaPlayer complete");
        }
    });
    _mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    _mediaSession.setActive(false);
    _mediaPlayer.release();
    _mediaSession.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {
    return new BrowserRoot("", null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {

}
```

}